# How to persistently set an environment in Python WHILE working around the 1024 character limit

Tags: python, environment-variables, global-variables, registry, limit

I'm writing a program for Python 3 in Windows which is trying to append to the Machine PATH variable. The trouble is that the PATH variable is longer than 1024 characters, which is an artificial limit that windows implements for BAT strings, and registry key-value pair values. Windows will, however, let you have a path up to about 32,000 characters without throwing a fit. If your PATH is over the lower character limit, I've found that it is significantly harder to set a machine variable, for the following reasons:

- `os.environ()` will return the full value, out to 32,000 characters.
- Trying to set the variable with `os.system('SETX [...]')` will only write out to 1024 characters, and truncate the rest. This is inevitably asking to ruin the system.
- `os.environ['PATH'] = '...'` will set the variable, but not persistently.
- One may think that editing the registry value for PATH would be an appropriate option, but the registry value under `'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'` only holds the first 1024 characters, rounded down to the nearest path.

In Python, how does one persistently set an environment variable which is longer than the conventional limit of 1024 characters. Windows says that the conventional limit is actually 2048 characters, but many limits are set at 1024 characters.

Comment: Why do you need to change Windows environment variable `PATH`, even in its _system-wide_  part? The only reason for its existence is making easy life of _command-line_ lovers and frequent users. _When a command is issued at the CMD prompt, the operating system will first look for an executable file in the current folder, if not found it will scan `%PATH%` to find it._… So I can type e.g. `python` instead of `C:\Python\Python38\python.exe` from an open `cmd` prompt; I have it in `%path%` because I **often** launch `python` from `cmd`.

Comment: @JosefZ you answered your own question

Comment: On the contrary, I do not have e.g. `gimp` or `iexplore` in `path` because I **never** launch ˙them from `cmd` prompt (but using other methods like from context menu, from start menu etc.) If you _need_ to have something in `path` then use rather its _user_ part in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`.